# What fieldtype to choose and how to look my query

Tags: solr

The problem is this: I've got a column (named **name**)which consist of names for Example "Иван Кирилов Петров", "Нина Семова Мариножа" and so on.

So I want to make a query which will get all the names that has first name 'Иван' and last name 'Петров'; The second name doesn't matter  so i will put `*` wildcard character.

Also there is a bigger problem: I should be able in a case if the user writes "Иван Кирилов Петров" to find this exact person

what I have tried :

I made the field `text_ws` type
and tested the following queries:

```
q=name:Иван*Петров
```

perfect - it finds what I want - all the names with first `Иван` and last `Петров`;

But then i want to find Иван Кирилов Петров i get no response because I want to make an exact search and my type should be string

How can I solve this!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true"](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Data_Types) flag on your text_ws type definition. And use debugQuery=true flag to see how it does the matches against the field. If the basic thing work, you can then look at [pf3 flag in eDismax configuration](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#pf3_.28Phrase_trigram_fields.29) to boost the query matches.

Solr also comes with dedicated Token Filters for Russian, but you probably don't care about that for the people's names.

Comment: hey thnank you Alexandre, but I don't know how suddenly the case where I search a person by first and last name doesn't work - q=name:Иван*Петров
and ican't explain why   but now when i write "ИВАН МИНЧЕВ ПЕТРОВ" it works

Comment: Use debugQuery and see what happens. Also, in Solr4 Admin WebUI, there is analysis tab, you can put text there and see what comes out.
Finally, with eDismax you can search against multiple fields at once, so maybe you need copyField and different processing on different fields to handle different scenarios. In the end, it is all about tokenization (analyzers on your text type), so in complex cases you do have to think it through.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a wild-card query. If you are only splitting on white-space during index time (`text_ws`) and you get complete first, last and/or middle names for query, you can do an AND query like

```
q=name:(Иван AND Петров)
```

or

```
q=name:(ИВАН AND МИНЧЕВ AND ПЕТРОВ)
```

**Update**: After your comment, I see that this will do a bag-of-words search and won't preserve the order. I guess you need to keep a string [copy field](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields) of `name`, say `name_str`, which will give you more search options. For example, if there are 2 spaces in the query, meaning you get the first, middle and last names, then you can do an exact match on `name_str` like

```
q=name_str:"ИВАН%20МИНЧЕВ%20ПЕТРОВ"
```

If you are using Solr 4.0 and above, then regex query on the string field can help you. You can do

```
q=name_str:/ИВАН.*ПЕТРОВ/
```

will match anything that begins with `ИВАН` and ends with `ПЕТРОВ`.

or even

```
q=name_str:/Иван.*?Кирилов.*?Петров/
```

Unfortunately, there is no Solr wiki page on regex search yet, but you can google around.

You need to distinguish between the different types of queries you want to do and do different searches. Maybe give a check-box to your users asking if they want an exact match or not.

Comment: NO unfortunately q=name:(Иван AND Петров) gives me the names with second name Петров; oh it seems thay a wildcar character in field with withspaces is really a nightmare

Comment: i made name: string and I tried q=name:/ИВАН.*ПЕТРОВ/
Ubfortunately it doesn't find any result